# Set icon on action bar on every activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I want to add the app's icon to the action bar in every activity.

I know that there are a lot of questions like this on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions worked so far.

What I've tried:

```
1. <application
       android:logo="@mipmap/ic_logo"

2. <activity
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
```

There are also solutions by Java code, but I don't want to use it since I have many activities, and I rather method that can be controlled through one file and not many files.

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: put it into menu-items for toolbar?!

Comment: Why not make a base activity that handles the logic for instantiating the toolbar etc? Then extend that activity class in ALL of your activities? Overriding functionality as needed?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I don't want to add it as a menu item, since then it will be shown after the title on the action bar, while I want it between the back button and the action bar.

Comment: @fzxt As I wrote, I don't want a solution by Java code, since then I have to make changes in all of my activities, and there are many of them.

Comment: You can position it where you want...

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot How can I position it there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702196/android-position-menu-items-in-toolbar-layout

Comment: just like in every other layout...

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I've added `getSupportActionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);` to solve it. Just one more question. Do you know how to set icon where there is no toolbar initialized in the layout, but there is still a toolbar on the activity itself.

Comment: you will get a null pointer exception if it is not initialized.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I know. It is not initialized. It is probably shown because of the selected theme.

Comment: uh. It has no need to be initialized that way

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yes, but how can I add the icon to it?

Comment: I don't get your question mate.

Comment: You maybe should provide pictures and code of what you are trying to approve and what you are getting..

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot What I currently have is a toolbar which I didn't initialize, since it's came with the app theme. I want to add it an icon like I did to the initialized toolbars. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

where R.mipmap.ic_launcher is your icon logo